# I'm getting multiple cloned items with jquery, what is best way to use it in a dynamic loop?

Tags: jquery, clone

I want to clone a div based on the user input. If user inputs 1, div gets copied 1 time, if user inputs 2, div gets copied 2 times (and previously copied div gets removed of course).

This is my code:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {

var dtotal = parseInt($('input').val());
var $dragcont = $('#parent');
var $dragon = $("#child:not('.cloned')");

for(var i=0;i < dtotal; i++){
$dragon.clone().addClass('cloned').appendTo($dragcont);
}
```

I have achieved this with php (form action) but in this case I'm not allowed to fiddle with server side. Help.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0oL360p8/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review this [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try not to use id on a div that will be copied. Id is suppose to be unique, so I've changed it to a class instead.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var dtotal = parseInt($('input').val());
  var $dragcont = $('#parent');
  var $dragon = $(".child:not('.cloned')");
  
  // If you want to remove previously copied.
  $dragcont.find('.child.cloned').remove();
  
  for(var i=0 ;i <dtotal; i++){
    var $el = $dragon.clone().addClass('cloned');
    $el.appendTo($dragcont);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <p class="child">Clone me</p>
</div>  
  <input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thanke @smoksnes for the solution, marked as answered.